# Как сделать фигуру Shape в форме правильного круга при отображении на всех экранах

Tags: java, android

Пробую сделать круглые блоки в меню, но на разных устройствах выглядит по разному. Собстна вопрос, как сделать что бы на всех устройствах они были идеально круглые?

Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>
   <solid android:color="#4CAF50" >
   </solid>
  <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD** . Для создания виджета с фоном в форме правильного круга, картинкой (здесь *res/drawable/rating.png*) и подписью снизу, произвольного размера, используется такая конструкция:

**res/drawable/image_in_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#4CAF50"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rating"
          android:bottom="5dp"
          android:left="5dp"
          android:right="5dp"
          android:top="5dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

размер круга будет подгонятся под размер вложенной картинки с отступами 5dp

использование:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/image_in_circle"
    android:text="камера"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
```

Результат на всех экранах одинаков:
[image: screen]

так же нелишним будет указать, что за фигуру вы рисуете (`android:shape="oval"`), так как `Shape` рисует и прямоугольник и дуги и др.

PS: в вашей разметке цвет, указанный первым (#FFFFFF) ни на что не влияет

Comment: Разве будет правильно что я укажу размеры? например на других устройствах (на планшете) овалы будут выглядит не так как нужно

Comment: исправил ответ чтобы подгонялось под `wrap_content` все

Comment: все отлично, но нужен padding, а то сейчас выглядит так: http://cs627122.vk.me/v627122400/25979/pHSLxconuw0.jpg

Comment: паддинг указывается для изображения, в моем примере он `5dp` (параметры - android:left, android:right, android:top и android:bottom соответственно для отстуупа слева, справа сверху и снизу)

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя размерность блока, к которому ты применяешь Shape, WRAP_CONTENT, то у тебя скорей всего растягивается круг.

Есть плохое решение: задать строго размерность блока (подогнать, чтобы было идеально) и тогда у тебя не будет растягиваться. Это настраивается через layout'ы.