# Как объединить ImageView и TextView в один класс? (Android)

Tags: java, android, view, android-customview

Нужна View, у которой будет возможность поставить атрибуты `background` (фон), `src` (основное изображение) и `text`.

[image: Вот пример. Рамка - основное изображение, под ней ещё должен быть фон, а сверху текст]

Вот пример: "металлическая" рамка - основное изображение, под ней ещё должен быть фон в виде какого-нибудь изображения, а сверху текст

Как это сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете использовать `layer-list` в качестве фона для `TextView`, в котором разместить любое количество графических элементов. Как [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471774/177345)

Answer (score 1):

У меня аналогичная проблема решается так (изображение с наложенным текстом над ним):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageHint"
        android:text="@string/imageHint"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/increased_text_size"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется можно гораздо проще:

```
Spanned sFromHtml = Html.fromHtml(sHTMLstring);
textView.setText(sFromHtml);
```

sHTMLstring - строка с html разметкой `<img src=''>` позволит отобразить картинку

Comment: Использовать HTML в нативном приложении никак нельзя назвать разумным решением. Система имеет достаточно собственных инструментов для такого виджета, чтобы использовать веб-костыли какие-то.

Comment: почему костыли ?! Это стандартная возможность ... если не нравится html, можно иначе: https://habrahabr.ru/post/167343/ в любом случае подходит это в данном конкретном случае или нет я не знаю

Comment: `Spannable` в данном примере то же самое, что и в вашем ответе. строка `Html.fromHtml()` неявно преобразуется в `Spannable`/ Костыль это потому, что система Android не web-система, вроде ChromeOS и ее виджеты это классы Java, а не веб-страницы. C Java-классами работают через Java-код, а HTML место в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `FrameLayout`, в который снизу положите `ImageView`, а сверху `TextView`

Comment: Кажется мне, что автор хочет несколько иного/большего. Вроде как ему надо это ещё и в CustomView обернуть, чтобы в xml одним тегом пихать и атрибутами картинки и текст назначать.

Comment: Вы правы, Юрий. Способ с несколькими View я уже использую, но хотелось бы всё в одном.

Answer (score 0):

Дык это жи просто. Берешь TextView пишешь текст 3. картинку метала ставишь в foregorund он есть в TExtView. А другую картину ставишь в background он тоже есть в TextVuew и Вуяла.