# ImageView и покрывающий его круглый прозрачный градиент

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

**Дано:**

ImageView, в который загружена круглая .png картинка.

**Как программно добавить поверх картинки круглый градиент из drawable.xml ?**

При этом сквозь градиент должно быть видно картинку.

**UPD:**

ImageView я добавляю на экран кодом:

```
linearLayout.addView(imageView)
```

При клике на ImageView нужно, чтобы появился прозрачный градиент в этом ImageView и через определенное время убрался.

По идеи можно прописать все ImageView(их 50, кол-во не меняется) в layout'е и обернуть ImageView в какой нибудь lаyout, добавив в него еще одну ImageView с градиентом, которую я буду делать визибл при нажатии.

На сколько плохо такое решение будет ?

Код как я добавляю картинки:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setId(i);
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 8, 0);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.pic1));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    layout.addView(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471774/177345), как совмещены картинка и фигура, делаете аналогично, только фигура с градиентом

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо за отклик. Я создаю ImageView динамически и по идеи нужно также динамически в коде задавать drawable. Поправте, если я не так понимаю. Обновли ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2470289/3212712) делается это с помощью `android:type="radial"` так:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="250"
        android:startColor="#88E9E9E9" android:endColor="#88D4D4D4" />
</shape>
```

Прозрачность при этом [делается](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647029/3212712) проставлением значений альфа-канала в цвете. Это первые две цифры.

При этом, чтобы градиент был сверху изображения можно

1. Использовать [`selector`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475523/17609)
2. картинку поместить в фон, а градиент как изображение `ImageView`
3. Или наложить поверх `ImageView` ещё один `ImageView`, в коий и поместить градиент любым способом.
4. Извратиться, перевести оба изображения в `BitMap` и наложить попиксельно)

Comment: Все гораздо проще, чем предложеные вами три способа - для совмещения изображений [есть `layer-list`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471774/177345)

Comment: Юрий, спасибо за отклик. Загвоздка в том, что мне нужно динамически добавлять/убирать градиент для ImageView в коде. Возможно, Ваш второй способ подойдет, накладывать поверх первого ImageView еще один с градиентом.

Comment: @researcher, да, в такой ситуации я как раз второй способ юзаю)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб круто) Возможно у Вас есть пример кода как заместить ImageView другим ImageView с градиентом прозрачным?) Я думаю имплементировать интерфейс OnClick и там разбирать какой именно ImageView был нажат и тогда поверх него накладывать другой ImageView с градиентом.

Comment: @researcher, у меня просто вьюха с градиентов видимой/невидимой делается) Никакой магии)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 100% Ваша правда) Получается, Вы при формировнаии списка из ImageView добавляете туда не одну ImageView, а две - одну с картинкой, а вторую с градиентом, но не видимую и потом протсо показываете ImageView с градиентом ?)

Comment: @researcher, да, всё верно. Приходится, конечно, делать так, чтобы одна над другой точно разполагалась, т..е лишние вьюхи в иерархии получаются... Зато полный контроль - захотел показал, захотел - убрал)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, сейчас попробую реализовать это)

Comment: Юрий, помогите, пожалуйста разобраться с этим "Или наложить поверх ImageView ещё один ImageView, в коий и поместить градиент любым способом." Не могу понять как это сделать. Как при OnClick добавить ImageView поверх именно нажатого ImageView?

Comment: Создал [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475494/imageview-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC-imageview] (вопрос), если можно, загляните туда.