# ImageView перекрыть другим ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-scrollview

**Имеем**:

У меня в приложении должно быть много картинок(порядка 50-60), они размещаться по 10-15 штук в HorizontalScrollView->LinearLayout

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            //тут картинки
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Туда их можно добавлять динамически(как сейчас я делаю):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setId(i);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.pic1));
    layout.addView(imageView);
}
```

Либо же картинки можно прописывать в разметке(не рациональный вариант)

**Что нужно:**

Сделать так, чтобы при нажатию на какую-либо картинку, поверх нее появился прозрачный градиент из drawable:

```
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="#65a777fd"
            android:endColor="#650999e4">
        </gradient>
    </shape>
```

Когда пользователь нажмет на другую картинку - градиент с первой уберется и появится на другой картинке.

**Проблема:**

Не понимаю как обработать это все в OnClick. Как получить ImageView, чтобы задать ей градиент? Как потом отменить его для ImageView?

Прошу помочь в решение данной задачи. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужно обрабатывать состояние `selected`, а не самому что то прикручивать.

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо за отклик. Я немного не понял что Вы имеете ввиду, Вы можете немного подробнее написать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таки @pavlofff прав, это можно через `selector` сделать.

1. Создаём `selector` - файл `my_selector.xml` в `res/drawable`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <!-- когда нажато показывать ИМЯ_ГРАДИЕНТА.xml-->
       <item
           android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/ИМЯ_ГРАДИЕНТА" />

       <item
           android:drawable="@drawable/ИМЯ_СТАНДАРТНОЙ_КАРНИНКИ" />
   </selector>
   ```
2. Присваиваем его как изображение для `ImageView`

   ```
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
   imageView.setId(i);
   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.my_selector );
   layout.addView(imageView);
   ```
3. Не забываем сделать родительский элемент кликабельным:

   ```
      <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/ll"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >
   ```

---

Ещё можно добавлять в разметку на ImageView, a FrameLayout c двумя ImageView внутри, один поверх другого. И им назначать разные картинки.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    FrameLayout fr = new FrameLayout(this);
    fr.setClickable(true);
    layout.addView(fr);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setId(i);
    imageView.setImage(R.drawable.pic1);
    fr.addView(imageView);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setId(i+1000);
    //устанавливаем по умолчанию пустую картинку
    imageView.setImageResource(null);
    fr.addView(imageView);
}
```

Далее по нажатию на картинку ставим ей градиент

imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ГРАДИЕНТ);

И когда надо всё убрать - пробегаемся циклом по всем картинкам и ставим им пустые изображения

imageView.setImageResource(null);

Comment: Юрий спасибо за отклик. Но мне совсем это нужно. Когда я нажму на изображение, повер него появится градиент. Этот градиент уберется после определенного события, например нажатия на другую картинку. (а если быть более точным, то при нажатию на кратинку - запускается проигрывание мелодии в MediaPlayer, когда мелодия закончит играть - я уберу градиент с картинки)

Comment: См. обновлённый ответ

Comment: "Далее по нажатию на картинку ставим ей градиент" А как мне повесить OnClick на все картинки ? Или сделать класс Implements OnClickListener ? и как-то в OnClick определять какая картинка была нажата?

Comment: Пришла такая идея(не уверен, что правильно): можно при addView заносить как-то ИД вьюхи в массив и потом этот массив в цикле перебирать и задавать ему значение без градиента..

Comment: @researcher, да в том же цикле и вешать... Определять можно просто по `id`. А вообще в данном случае вам лучше использовать `RecyclerVeiw` и горизонтальный `LayoutManager` для него. Там в качестве элемента ставите предложенную разметку и в onClick вы будете получать `position` нажатого элемента.

Comment: @researcher, да можно и так. Но вам таки всё же через RecyclerVeiw надо делать. В данном виде решение вашей задачи - тот ещё костыль.

Comment: Над RecyclerView подумаю, спасибо. Я не понимаю как получить ид вьюхи(будт то баттон или картинка), чтобы это значение занести в массив и потом, когда нужно, обратиться в этот массив и получить ссылку на эту вью и изменить именно этому вью какой-то параметр.

Comment: @researcher, вы назначаете id метод setId(). Заносите их в массив. Потом можно их по id найти методом `findviewDyId(id)`. Но это костыль. Надо через RecyclerVeiw

Comment: Юрий! Большое спасибо Вам! Был бы в СПБ - руку пожал бы:) Сделал без RecyclerView, но это временно.

Comment: @researcher, пожалуйста) Главное помнить, что пока вы вручную назначаете `id` вьюхам вы не гарантируете их уникальности. Это может быть гарантировано только системой, когда она сама формирует `id` из разметки до компиляции. Так что как временный вариант оно подойдёт, да, но лучше делать через RecyclerView. Так будет в т.ч. выигрыш по производительности)

Comment: Вы права, Юрий. Я в принципе не люблю костылей и прочего, он так сейчас надо. Я сначала вообще хотел сделать в разметке такое) Т.е. прописать КАЖДУЮ ImageView в разметке) И все вытекающее.. Вы помогли мне очень!

Answer (score 0):

Для каждой картинки задайте `OnTouchListener`, а уже в нем по нажатию и отпусканию показывайте градиент.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        // убрать градиент
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
        // добавить градиент
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Немного не то нужно. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии градиент остался на картинке, до определенного времени, например до нажатия по другой картинке.